# Is a "start", "run" or "execute" method a good practice?

Tags: object-oriented-design, construction, constructors

I'm currently working on a code base that has many classes that implement a Start method. 
This seems like two-phase construction to me, which I had always considered a bad practice.  I can't tell the difference between this and a constructor.

When is it appropriate to use a start method instead of normal object construction?

When should I prefer to use the constructor?

Edit: 
I don't think it is that relevant but the programming language is C#, it could equally apply to Java or C++

Comment: Could you add a bit more context? Language? Threaded vs single thread? difference between `start` and the constructor? etc...

Comment: @MichaelT I can see why you're asking, but I'm interested in the general principle behind when it's appropriate. I'm concerned that if I gave specific examples from the code base I'm working on, the answers would be too focused on the details and not on my specific questions.

Comment: this is a largely overrated dichotomy, maintained by those who don't know [The way of the Future...](http://blog.softmemes.com/2012/06/18/the-way-of-the-future-futures-in-net-java-and-javascript/)

Comment: @DaveHillier For example, in perl it is standard practice (and a good one) to have an `init` method of some sort outside of the `new` function - http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html .  The idioms of one language may work well there and not in other languages.

Comment: @gnat would a future not use the constructor of the object?

Comment: @MichaelT good answer :)

Comment: @DaveHillier opposite - you define futures in constructor, for later use (where "later" could be [as late as possible](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#blocking "as discussed eg in Scala SIP-14 / Blocking section"))

Comment: Examples of classes with `Start` methods in common APIs include threads and stopwatches.

Comment: Count me among those who need a code sample to understand what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A `Start()` method (like `Run()`, `Execute()` or anything similar) is appropriate when the cost of constructing the object is low, but the cost of *using* it is high.  For example: A class which encapsulates a best-path-optimization algorithm.  It's trivial to set it up with a set of parameters (`X` squares by `Y` squares, with suchandsuch evaluation method), but it may take a while to execute.  If you want to create 20 of these objects, you may want to delay execution until all of them have been created - this lets you parallelize them easier, for example.

Alternatively, it could be useful when you don't know when the object is going to be needed to start - perhaps because it's based on user input, or logic which selects from a list of possibilities.

This assumes, of course, that `Start()` is the useful method on the object, and not an equivalent to an `Initialize()` method.  If it is just an extra way to set more parameters, it shouldn't exist.

Comment: Another use for a start method is when the action done also creates a new worker thread or a timer. The constructor should not do this kind of heavy lifting or generate significant side effects (like creating a new thread).

Answer (score 50):

[Code Complete](http://cc2e.com/) (and many other software engineering resources) emphasizes matching your classes to real world objects. I believe the fundamental reason for this is that it makes it more likely that you have a true grasp of what it is that you're implementing, rather than hacking away at an intangible idea.

If you're a subscriber to this theory, I don't see anything wrong with adding a `Start()` method to any class that should, were it a real object, also have a resting state. If it doesn't make any sense for your object to exist while not running (or doesn't make any sense for your object to be running at all), then I would say it is bad practice.

Comment: A good analogy.  It's worth noting that `Start()` could correspond to either an on/off switch (like a lightswitch) which should then have a `Stop()`, or to a push-button (like the Print button on a copy machine) where it kicks off and then runs until done.

Comment: +1 well said and welcome to P.SE, answers like this are a great start.

Answer (score 14):

You may use [lazy initialization.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)

> In computer programming, lazy initialization is the tactic of delaying
>   the creation of an object, the calculation of a value, or some other
>   expensive process until the first time it is needed.

**That way you avoid temporal-coupling, meaning the consumer of your class has to call certain methods in certain order.** Having to call `start()` first is a way of having to know how the class works internally, which is bad because you may change that in the future.

Delay the expensive initialization until it's first needed..

**Example:**

```
public class FooClass{

    private ExpensiveResource resource;
    private CheapResource cheap;

    public  FooClass(String someParameter){
        // constructor: initialize CheapResource cheap 
            // but NOT ExpensiveResource resource
    }

    public ExpensiveResource getExpensiveResource(){
        if (resource == null) {
            this.initializeExpensiveResource();     
        }
        return this.resource
    }

    public String getExpensiveResourceName(){
        if (resource == null) {
            this.initializeExpensiveResource();     
        }
        return this.resource.getName();
    }   

    public CheapResource getCheapResource(){
        return this.cheap;
    }

    private initializeExpensiveResource(){
        // do expensive initialization of field "resource"
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Test{
    public static void main (String args[]){

        FooClass foo = new FooClass("some string");
        CheapResource cr = foo.getCheapResource();
        String s = foo.getExpensiveResourceName(); 
          // just now is the expensive resource initialized

    }
}
```

Comment: Another benefit of lazy initialization that is worth noting is that it takes very little effort to form it into a [virtual proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern). Depending on the situation, this can be very useful for displaying _something_ while waiting for a resource to load (especially useful for things like remote images). Based on the original question, I don't think this is actually what the OP was gunning for, but thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @DanAlbert you're right it's not what I was asking for but still interesting